# Difference between Gabor filters, Gabor wavelets and Log-Gaber wavelets

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, gabor

I am a beginner in the field of image processing, and I am trying to understand Gabor transform but the more I read, the more I get confused.

So I wish to find someone who can help me answering this question: **what is the difference between a Gabor filter bank, a Gabor wavelet and a Log-Gabor wavelet?**

Comment: You might want to stop with #1.  Otherwise you're asking many questions that may be better off asked in a new question based on the answer to #1.

Comment: Looks like someone beat you to it! :-)